# Why won't Lubuntu connect to my wifi?

Tags: wireless, lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu 14.4.01 on my netbook.

I input my wifi details in Network Connections, and I'm pretty sure I have everything right.  But it doesn't even seem to try to connect!

```
sudo iwlist eth0 auth
eth0      no authentication information.


sudo iwlist eth1 auth
eth1      no authentication information.
```

EDIT: I will add that I can briefly see some kind of 'firmware warning' on startup.  (EDIT 2: It goes too fast to read but I do see 'b43-phy0' as part of it.)

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>